# Java 1.6 on Mac OS X 10.5?

Tags: macos, java

I'm running OS X 10.5.8 on an Intel iMac and don't have any immediate plans to upgrade to Snow Leopard. Am I able to upgrade Java to 1.6 somehow?

The [release notes on Apple's website for Java](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL971) are kind of cryptic and aren't clear what is necessary to upgrade Java to 1.6. (they mention that 1.6 only works on 64-bit Intel Macs... how do I know whether my Intel Mac is 64-bit or not?)

**edit:** `java -version` says I'm running J2SE 1.5.0_19 and I don't understand how to upgrade from Java 1.5 to 1.6

update: I just downloaded the [Java update from Apple](http://www.apple.com/downloads/macosx/apple/application_updates/javaformacosx105update5.html), and I'm now running J2SE 1.5.0_20, not 1.6... argh.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Grumble. There are multiple versions of Java that can coexist on Mac OSX, and you have to run [Java Preferences (in /Applications/Utilities) to select the default version](http://adam.shand.net/iki/2009/selecting_java_version_on_mac_osx_10_5_leopard/).

I love my iMac but sometimes Apple just doesn't bother explaining some really simple stuff that would make life a lot easier.

So now I am running 1.6.0_15 successfully.

Comment: Mark your own comment as the correct answer, cause day'um you just saved me an hour of work.

Answer (score 3):

For checking if you have a 32-bit or 64-bit Intel Mac, see [Apples thorough KB article](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3696).

For updating Java, have you tried [software update](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1338?viewlocale=en_US) yet? You can also download Java SE 6 [from Apple](http://www.apple.com/downloads/macosx/apple/application_updates/javaformacosx105update5.html).

Comment: yay, I have a Core 2 Duo, so it's a 64-bit processor. thanks!

Comment: It's still not clear from their download page how to upgrade from Java 1.5 -> 1.6 (the webpage makes it look like you have to have 1.6 already to upgrade to the latest 1.6 version.)