# Can't install Java 1.6 on OS X 10.5.8

Tags: java, osx-leopard

The official Apple updates only get me up to `java version "1.5.0_30"`. I'm trying to apply the 1.6 update manually from `JavaForMacOSX10.5Update6.pkg` and it gives me

> A newer version of this package is already installed

I tried this:

```
cd /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions
sudo rm -fr CurrentJDK
sudo ln -s 1.6 CurrentJDK
```

and no good... How can I get 1.6?

I even looked [at this question](https://superuser.com/questions/100078/java-1-6-on-mac-os-x-10-5) installed Update 10, and now I have 1.6 and 1.6.0 in `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions`
and the `current` folder also has the 1.6 files,
but in the java preferences i have only 1.4.2 and J2SE 5.0 (1.5)

[image: java-preferences]

**UPDATE**: It appears 32 bit OSX support only up to 1.5, and ther's no official way to run 1.6 on non- 64 bit...
is there a way around it? I'm trying to run PHPstorm whic requires 1.6

Comment: Also, it's probably a *very* bad idea to `rm` and move around stuff there.

Comment: Can you check what version you have installed?

Comment: @soandos 1.5.0_30

Comment: Just to get an overview, can you add a `ls -l /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions`?

Comment: And what's more, it has to be 64-bit *intel*!