# How to install 32bit Java 1.6 on OSX 10.5?

Tags: java, osx-leopard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can't install Java 1.6 on OS X 10.5.8](https://superuser.com/questions/314831/cant-install-java-1-6-on-os-x-10-5-8)

Is there a way to do it?
I'm trying to run PHPstorm which requires java 1.6, but my mac is 32 bit (core duo).

Comment: Please be as specific as you can in your questions. You didn't mention anything like that in your previous one.. give us as many details as possible and don't post the same question again!

Comment: @slhck my previous question was claimed to be a duplicate, which may be it was but the original question was not solved, and mine was much more detailed, so I cant add info to the original since it is closed and no one can answer it! so maybe instead of just closing you should offer a solution for how should I post to get this problem solved

Comment: Your [other question](http://superuser.com/questions/314831/cant-install-java-1-6-on-os-x-10-5-8) is **not closed** as a duplicate -- in fact I suggested to reopen again as I saw you had a more complex problem. And I asked you to add some more information, please. You may edit it freely.

Comment: @slhck thanx :)